# CalculateField_management

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop

How to put the field from arcpy.GetParameterAsText() into the expression here:
CalculateField_management(in_table, field, **expression**, {expression_type}, {code_block})

Now it is like **"!Name!.replace(\"о\",\"r\")"**
but here the field *!Name!* is already firmly defined and isn't depend on arcpy.GetParameterAsText()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [arcpy.GetParameterAsText](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000047000000) in order to let your users to specify the field they want to work with. Something like:

```
in_field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
CalculateField_management(in_table, in_field, expression, expression_type, code_block)
```

When in doubt of syntax of using the tool in Python, always consult the Help page. There are examples of using [Calculate Field GP tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004m000000) in a script.

When you author your script tool, you would need to define the input parameter. This will be an input text box in the script tool dialog that will let users specify the field. If you want to build a more advanced logic where users are allowed to choose a field from a list of fields the chosen feature class has, then you need to take a look at the [script tool parameters help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Setting_script_tool_parameters/00150000000n000000/). Look for Obtained from property of the parameter: this will let you "connect" your in_field parameter to the feature class specified and the list of fields available will be automatically shown to the user. From the help page:

> For input parameters, Obtained from contains the name of other
>   parameters used by the data type. For example, for an input field data
>   type, Obtained from is set to the name of the table parameter
>   containing the fields, as illustrated below.

Comment: I know that but the question is to put this "in_field" into the expression

Comment: @user16307 I think you need to edit your question and provide more details of what you have done and where you are stuck.

Comment: @PolyGeo, edited

Comment: I think what you talk about it is that you want to paste the name of the field in the expression string. This can be done by using this syntax for instance: "!{0}!.replace(\"о\",\"r\")"".format(in_field)

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov спасибо! Now it works :)

Comment: @user16307, glad it played out well! You could probably meet another formatting options in some Esri samples or on the Internet when the % is used. Compare them here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format. Keep in mind that you are able to use more than one {} in your strings. The "0" is the index position, so you could have "{0} * 10 / {1}".format(field1,field2). Good luck!